# Reading the specific data from the file using Vector function C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, vector, import

I am a new in C++ and have difficulties in importing specific data (numbers) from the file.
My input looks like:

```
Open    High    Low     Close
1.11476 1.11709 1.10426 1.10533
1.10532 1.11212 1.10321 1.10836
1.10834 1.11177 1.10649 1.11139
1.09946 1.10955 1.09691 1.10556  
1.10757 1.11254 1.09914 1.10361
1.10359 1.12162 1.10301 1.11595
1.09995 1.10851 1.09652 1.10097
```

I use the following code which works fine for me to read the second column entirely, however I need to read specific data only. For example the third row/ third column which is 1.10649
How can I read specific data? Do I need to use the **string** to get the row/column and then convert it to **int** in order to read it in a **vector**?  I am open for any suggestions and would be greatly appreciated if any could help me with this issue.

```
// Data import 2nd Column

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int columns = 4;

    vector< vector <double> > data;

  ifstream market_data("market_data.txt");

    if (market_data.is_open()) {
        double num;

        vector <double> line;

        while (market_data >> num) {
            line.push_back(num);

            if (line.size() == columns) {
                data.push_back(line);
                line.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    vector <double> column;
    double col = 2;

    for (double i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        column.push_back(data[i][col - 1]);
        cout << column[i] << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for replies.. I have solved the issue. So instead of:

```
vector <double> column;
    double col = 2;

for (double i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    column.push_back(data[i][col - 1]);
    cout << column[i] << endl;
}
```

enough to write:

> cout << data[2][2] << endl;

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a integer value for indexing (`size_t` to be precise), change

```
 for (double i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
```

to

```
 for( size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
   // ^^^^^^
```

Otherwise everything seems fine from your code sample.

Comment: Why not change to "size_t to be precise" (You made the compiler issuing a signed/unsigned warning) ?

Comment: @DieterLücking Good idea, fixed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank u for the reply, but by changing to size_t  does not solve the issue, the output is still the same.. All i need is to get the output of 1.10649 among all data

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers will always contain 7 characters (i assume it's not binary file), then you could make this simple.

Use seekg() method of ifstream.

Each number fills 10 characters (7 of number, 3 spaces). So, if you have table ROWS x COLUMNS, then to get specific number, you can do this:

```
const int ROW_LEN = 4
const int DATA_LEN = 10
...
int row,column;
double num;

std::cin >> row; //assume first row is 0
std::cin >> column //assume first column is 0

marked_data.seekg((column*ROW_LEN + row)*DATA_LEN);

marked_data >> num // here is your number
```

Comment: No, numbers are in text format and could vary in size actually. That's just bad advice based on assumptions of the input formats. The code for reading the numbers is already well done.

Comment: "If your numbers will always contain 7 characters". I know it's not universal, but it's faster for this specific problem. If you had 1000x1000 of these numbers, and then read them from random positions, it would be really, really slow.

Comment: Aaw. Well my brain tricked me - I forgot about newlines, so this code is broken anyway. If it's supposed to work, 1 (or 2, for \r\n) character/s must be taken into calculations. Sorry to give a wrong advice.

Comment: The latter flaw is even OS/file format specific. But nice to see new members actively participating here anyways.